# Distance of two lists with equal summation from a list

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

There are three given lists of numbers in **increasing order**

$$\ell=\{\ell_1,\ell_2,...,\ell_n\}; \ell_i \geq\ell_{i+1}$$
$$\Lambda=\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n\};\lambda_i \geq\lambda_{i+1}$$
$$\Psi=\{\psi_1,\psi_2,...,\psi_n\};\psi_i \geq\psi_{i+1}$$

We know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\psi_i$ is it true to claim that

**(1)**
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\ell_i-\lambda_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\ell_i-\psi_i)$$

**(2)**
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\ell_i-\lambda_i|= \sum_{i=1}^{n}|\ell_i-\psi_i|$$

If yes how to prove?

Comment: $\ell_i\ge\ell_{i+1}$ isn't what I would call **increasing order**.

Comment: @bof non decreasing ;)

Comment: Most people would call $\ell_i\le\ell_{i+1}$ "non decreasing order".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **(1)**

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\ell_i-\lambda_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ell_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i$

Since given $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\psi_i$

Therefore $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ell_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ell_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\psi_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\ell_i-\psi_i)$

Hence $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\ell_i-\lambda_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\ell_i-\psi_i)$$

For **(2)**

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\ell_i-\lambda_i|= \sum_{i=1}^{n}|\ell_i-\psi_i|$$ will hold true iff

$$\ell_i\le\lambda_i,\psi_i\ \ \ or\ \ \ \ell_i\ge\lambda_i,\psi_i$$

for each and every $i$.